# How can I replace the bulb in this ceiling fan?

Tags: ceiling-fan

So I moved into this house over a year ago, and upon moving in, there was a ceiling fan in the kitchen area that has continued to baffle me (and anybody I have look at it).  The core of it all seems to be 1 piece, the only thing that seems to have screws to be removed are the blades of the fan.  Here's some pictures:

[image]

[image]

[image]

*The little stump at the top of this picture that kind of looks like a screw is the switch to change the direction of the blades.

So it looks to me like the base of it is glued to the ceiling, and other than that I don't see anything.  To make matters worse, the bulb inside is very dim, and I can't for the life of me figure out how to replace the bulb, none of the pieces seem to come apart, I've tried several times and had a few other people look at it.

Has anybody seen a ceiling fan like this?  I'd like to either figure out how to change the bulb, or figure out how to just get rid of it entirely and put up one that makes a little more sense.

Comment: Have you tried twisting the white glass cover or the steel hub at the ceiling?

Comment: Are you trying to replace the bulb(s), or the whole fan?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Yes I've tried twisting everything, it'll turn a bit in each direction, but never seems to loosen, after a certain point you need to put force that feels like it's going to break the thing to continue turning (while going back and forth is relatively easy)

Comment: @Tester101 The answer to both questions would be beneficial to me, the bulb for the short term and the whole thing for the long term.

Comment: Try turning until it stops turning easily, and then pulling straight down. Counterclockwise would be the odds-on favorite for the direction in which you'd expect this to work. If no luck, try pushing up and continuing to turn (looking for just a little more followed by pull down to release). There are a number of things that work that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Removing the unit

As for how to remove the entire fan, I have a fan with a similar canopy. There's a decorative cover ring at the bottom, that hides two screws. You should be able to pop the cover down, then undo the screws. Once the canopy is out of the way, you should have no problem removing the entire unit.

[image]

To remove the decorative cover ring, you'll have to give it an 1/8th anticlockwise turn.

[image]

Notice with the ring removed, you have access to the screws that hold the canopy on (orange arrow). You can also see the slots in the decorative ring, where the screws slide in to hold it on (red arrow).

## Change the bulb

To change the bulb, you'll obviously have to remove the globe. To do so:

- Turn the globe about a 1/4 turn in the anticlockwise direction (you should feel it stop).
- Pull down.

Comment: That globe will not turn one bit, and it looks like that ring was glued on =(.

Comment: Have you tried pushing up, or pulling down on the globe a bit as you try to turn it?

Comment: Completely confident in which way it needed to turn I finally just put dangerous amounts of force into it and got it to come off, looks like it was just stuck on with years of gunk, but it is off now!  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

> **Has anybody seen a ceiling fan like this?**

That looks like a Minka-Aire Acero F601-BS/BN 52-inch Brushed Nickel-Steel Indoor Ceiling Fan

> **I'd like to either figure out how to change the bulb,**

The [manual](http://www.minka.com/sites/default/files/product_manuals/F601-English.pdf) is available from [their website](http://www.minka.com/minka-aire/products). The glass shade twists off.

> **or figure out how to just get rid of it entirely**

Turn the power off, cover the carpet and break out the Dremel :)

Comment: Man, I don't know what's gunked up inside this thing, but that glass shade does not twist off.  That manual will help a lot though, let's see if I can find some more clues.  Thanks for a step in the right direction.

Comment: I have a Minka-Aire with a similar globe. It does twist off as @Tester101 says. I feels like it's going to break, but it doesn't. Recommend two hands and a dishtowel over the glass (just in case).