# How to replace bulbs in this ceiling fan?

Tags: ceiling-fan

Unfortunately I have no documentation on this ceiling fan.   I've tried doing a google reverse image search and looked at the catalogs of popular ceiling fan manufacturers.

There are no screws or tabs or anything like that.   I've tried physically rotating the glass which appears to be bonded to the inner metal housing with no luck.

There's a small circular indentation in the inner housing but appears to serve no purpose.

[image]

[image: close up]

[image: Close up]

Comment: This is somewhat a duplicate of https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/48621/how-can-i-replace-the-bulb-in-this-ceiling-fan?rq=1 but the additional answers about little indents and bumping the glass will be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I almost  certain that the glass should rotate off, the little indent in the metal will be for a  corresponding groove in the  glass cover. Some times the friction on these make them feel as thought they will not move.

If you are careful and wrap the glass in a damp towel, or some other grippy material, and try turning with a little more force it should come free. It should be counterclockwise to undo it.

Comment: It may help to apply a little impact as well: while one person applies steady force to rotate the glass another person could slap or bump the glass upward or maybe sideways. The shock/vibration can help the stuck parts move.

Comment: There's never an circular indentation that serves no purpose..lol

Comment: The little indentation is well above the glass, but i will give the counterclockwise rotation another try.

Comment: It worked!   I'm not advising anyone to do what i did, but i took a rubber mallet and gave it some bangs kind of like @GregHill suggested.

Comment: As Alaska Man and @JACK  suggested, the circular indentations actually provided the thread part that holds the glass up.